# iphone app UIWebView cache data

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I need a UIWebView to show a html page. if internet is not available it will show the last downloaded version. if has internet then it downloads the most current version and replaces and shows the version just downloaded. how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could implement you webViews delegate `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method to grab the request and load it again. Since it was just finished loading, we can assume that it is cached and load it with synchronous networking. Store the result. When network is unavailable load that result into the webView using `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`. When network comes available agin just call `loadRequest:` to refresh.

Another option is to use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` with a javascript around:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
```

and inserting the content with `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`

But these two only work for pure HTML without images, sounds, etc.

A third option would be to use the `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad` when network is not available. see [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001695-DontLinkElementID_3)

You migth also have a look at the [NSURLCache](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/index.html)